# Can we connect two specific nodes in a different location in IBM-Cloud using IPSEC-VPN?

Tags: ibm-cloud, vpn

I want to transfer data between a server in location A and a server in Location B through IPSEC tunnel. If i create IPSEC-VPN in IBM cloud in location-A and Location-B, will it be possible to route the traffic which is between these specific nodes through IPESEC tunnel? All the other server traffic between these two locations has to take normal route. Is it possible.? any document reference is available? Please help.

Comment: Something like this? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-vpc-site2site-vpn

Comment: But VPC is only available for specific location in IBM_Cloud.